# Translatory motion of a rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

For the translatory motion of a rod, shouldn't the torque about every point of the rod be zero? There is no rotation about any point right?

Answer (score 1):

No.  If suppose the entire rod is rotating about a fixed axis. Like a rod is tied to both of its ends with strings to the ceiling of equal length. Now give a small impulse at the centre of mass of rod. The it starts swinging about the axis passing through the two hinges. In this case the rod is translatory motion. But even there is a torque acting.[image]

Comment: In translatory motion torque about an point on the rod is equal may or may not be zero.

Comment: May I add: In your picture the tangent component of the gravitational force causes a torque around the axis, which passes through the strings' contact points with the ceiling. However the rod itself "feels" more torques. The inertial and gravitational forces for the rod will crete internal torques around the two connection points with the strings. These internal torques will ultimately cancel out so they won't cause rotation, but they still exist and will cause stress.

Comment: Yes, If the internal torques won't cancel, then it will not be in translatory motion.

Comment: Well, if the rod is translating linearly with some acceleration, then what?